# Get 3 tables in SQL Server 2008, avoid using two loops and Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, loops

I want to get `3 tables` from one table named `@X_Table` (this table has the name of columns of `original table`) in `SQL 2008`:

**The Original table has lots of rows and 5 atributes (I could have more atributes like 30, but in the example I have 5 atributes):**

```
x1  x2   x3   x4   x5    
----------------------------
438 498  3625 3645 5000
438 498  3625 3648 5000
438 498  3625 3629 5000
437 501  3625 3626 5000
438 498  3626 3629 5000
439 498  3626 3629 5000
440 5000 3627 3628 5000
444 5021 3631 3634 5000
451 5025 3635 3639 5000
458 5022 3640 3644 5000
465 525  3646 3670 5000
473 533  3652 3676 5000
481 544  3658 3678 5000
484 544  3661 3665 5000
484 532  3669 3662 2945
482 520  3685 3664 2952
481 522  3682 3661 2955
480 525  3694 3664 2948
481 515  5018 3664 2956
479 5000 3696 3661 2953 
**...(EVEN MORE ROWS LIKE 100,000)** ...
```

First I am getting in other table the names of the columns(`the var @table_name` refers to the table above):

```
INSERT  @X_Table (ID,NAME) 
SELECT  [ID] = ORDINAL_POSITION, [NAME] = COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name
```

So I get the @X_Table:

**@X_Table:**

```
ID  NAME
------------
1   x1
2   x2
3   x3
4   x4
5   x5
```

Then `for each column` I want the `sum of all values in that column`
so all the values in xi, so
sum(x1), sum(x2), sum(x3), sum(x4), sum(x5)`

**Table 1: INT,VARCHAR,FLOAT**

```
ID Name  value
---------------------------
1   x1  48431
2   x2  138420
3   x3  192071
4   x4  192041
5   x5  204602
```

Then `for each column` I want the `sum of all values in that column multiplied by each column` for example
for column x1: `sum(x1*x1), sum(x1*x2), sum(x1*x3), sum(x1*x4), sum(x1*x5)`
for column x2: `sum(x2*x2), sum(x2*x3), sum(x2*x4), sum(x2*x5)`
for column x3: `sum(x3*x3), sum(x3*x4), sum(x3*x5)`
for column x4: `sum(x4*x4), sum(x4*x5)`
for column x5: `sum(x5*x5)`

**Table 2: INT, VARCHAR, FLOAT**

```
ID   Name     value
---------------------------
1   SUM(x1*x1)  83926421
2   SUM(x1*x2)  162997894
3   SUM(x1*x3)  186865166
4   SUM(x1*x4)  156224385
5   SUM(x1*x5)  168573557
6   SUM(x2*x2)  598228836
7   SUM(x2*x3)  542331010
8   SUM(x2*x4)  460990820
9   SUM(x2*x5)  512335365
10  SUM(x3*x3)  797430261
11  SUM(x3*x4)  659040569
12  SUM(x3*x5)  723779398
13  SUM(x4*x4)  677091478
14  SUM(x4*x5)  722922237
15  SUM(x5*x5)  808976398
```

Then for the last table I want the diagonal, or in other the xii of the table above

**Table 3: INT, VARCHAR, FLOAT**

```
ID   Name     value
---------------------------
1   SUM(x1*x1)  83926421
2   SUM(x2*x2)  598228836
3   SUM(x3*x3)  797430261
4   SUM(x4*x4)  677091478
5   SUM(x5*x5)  808976398
```

So To do so I am doing this approach, but I know This can be optimized,

```
SET @d = 5
WHILE (@counterI <= @d) BEGIN
        SELECT @nameThird   = NAME  FROM @X_Table where ID =  @counterI;
        SET    @nameFirst   = @nameThird;

    --INSERT FIRST TABLE
    SET @queryFirst = 'INSERT #FIRST_T (ID,NAME,Value) SELECT '+ CAST(@counterI AS VARCHAR)+' , '''+@nameFirst+''', SUM('+@nameFirst+') FROM '+ @table_name;
    EXEC (@queryFirst);

    --GET VALUE TO INSERT IN THIRD TABLE       
    SET @queryThird = 'INSERT #THIRD_T (ID,NAME,Value) SELECT '+CAST(@counterI AS VARCHAR)+' , '''+@nameThird+'*'+@nameThird+''', SUM('+@nameThird +'*'+@nameThird+') FROM '+  @table_name;
    EXEC (@queryThird);

    --Xij  
    WHILE (@counterJ <= @d) BEGIN           
        SELECT @nameThird2  = NAME  FROM @X_Table where ID =  @counterJ;
        SET @queryThird = 'INSERT #SECOND_T (ID,NAME,Value) SELECT '+CAST(@n AS VARCHAR)+' , '''+@nameThird+'*'+@nameThird2+''', SUM('+@nameThird +'*'+@nameThird2+') FROM '+  @table_name;
        EXEC (@queryThird);         
        SET @counterJ  = @counterJ + 1; 
        SET @n = @n +1  
    END         
    SET @counterI   = @counterI + 1; --reduce space
    SET @counterJ   = @counterI;
END
```

- How would you do this without these 2
  loops?,

(It takes a lot of time for tables with more than 30 attributes...)

**-----------------------------EDIT----------------------------**

When having more than 10 columns I am getting for the @table1 (answer by @Thomas)

ID Name Value

---

```
1   x1  8029145
2   x10 15453498
3   x11 13909514
4   x12 11336348
5   x13 11598240
6   x14 11951291
7   x15 12034693
8   x16 6558719
9   x17 5400520
10  x18 4966450
11  x19 5773049
12  x2  12696346
13  x20 5872404
14  x21 5542875
15  x22 9700954
16  x23 8484327
17  x24 8612340
18  x25 129470
19  x3  135818770
```

Is there some way to sort them by Name

```
x1,x2,x3,x4,x5...,x9,x10,x11....
```

instead of

```
x1,x10,x11,x19,x2,x3....?
```

So we get

```
ID Name Value
 -----------------
    1   x1  8029145
    2   x2  12696346
    3   x3  135818770
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Expanded source data to illustrate use of ordinal)

This problem is much easier if you normalize the structure. Since you are trying to do arithmetic on the columns, they need to be rows instead of columns.

```
Declare @X_Table Table
    (
    Id int not null Identity(1,1) Primary Key
    , x1 float not null
    , x2 float not null
    , x3 float not null
    , x4 float not null
    , x5 float not null
    , x111 float not null
    , x112 float not null
    , x113 float not null
    , x114 float not null
    , x115 float not null
    , x11 float not null
    , x12 float not null
    , x13 float not null
    , x14 float not null
    , x15 float not null
    )

Insert @X_Table( x1, x2, x3, x4, x5
    , x111, x112, x113, x114, x115 
    , x11, x12, x13, x14, x15 
    )
Select 438, 498, 3625, 3645, 5000, 438, 498, 3625, 3645, 5000, 438, 498, 3625, 3645, 5000
Union All Select 438, 498, 3625, 3648, 5000, 438, 498, 3625, 3648, 5000, 438, 498, 3625, 3648, 5000
Union All Select 438, 498, 3625, 3629, 5000, 438, 498, 3625, 3629, 5000, 438, 498, 3625, 3629, 5000
Union All Select 437, 501, 3625, 3626, 5000, 437, 501, 3625, 3626, 5000, 437, 501, 3625, 3626, 5000
Union All Select 438, 498, 3626, 3629, 5000, 438, 498, 3626, 3629, 5000, 438, 498, 3626, 3629, 5000
Union All Select 439, 498, 3626, 3629, 5000, 439, 498, 3626, 3629, 5000, 439, 498, 3626, 3629, 5000
Union All Select 440, 5000, 3627, 3628, 5000, 440, 5000, 3627, 3628, 5000, 440, 5000, 3627, 3628, 5000
Union All Select 444, 5021, 3631, 3634, 5000, 444, 5021, 3631, 3634, 5000, 444, 5021, 3631, 3634, 5000
Union All Select 451, 5025, 3635, 3639, 5000, 451, 5025, 3635, 3639, 5000, 451, 5025, 3635, 3639, 5000
Union All Select 458, 5022, 3640, 3644, 5000, 458, 5022, 3640, 3644, 5000, 458, 5022, 3640, 3644, 5000
Union All Select 465, 525, 3646, 3670, 5000, 465, 525, 3646, 3670, 5000, 465, 525, 3646, 3670, 5000
Union All Select 473, 533, 3652, 3676, 5000, 473, 533, 3652, 3676, 5000, 473, 533, 3652, 3676, 5000
Union All Select 481, 544, 3658, 3678, 5000, 481, 544, 3658, 3678, 5000, 481, 544, 3658, 3678, 5000
Union All Select 484, 544, 3661, 3665, 5000, 484, 544, 3661, 3665, 5000, 484, 544, 3661, 3665, 5000
Union All Select 484, 532, 3669, 3662, 2945, 484, 532, 3669, 3662, 2945, 484, 532, 3669, 3662, 2945
Union All Select 482, 520, 3685, 3664, 2952, 482, 520, 3685, 3664, 2952, 482, 520, 3685, 3664, 2952
Union All Select 481, 522, 3682, 3661, 2955, 481, 522, 3682, 3661, 2955, 481, 522, 3682, 3661, 2955
Union All Select 480, 525, 3694, 3664, 2948, 480, 525, 3694, 3664, 2948, 480, 525, 3694, 3664, 2948
Union All Select 481, 515, 5018, 3664, 2956, 481, 515, 5018, 3664, 2956, 481, 515, 5018, 3664, 2956
Union All Select 479, 5000, 3696, 3661, 2953, 479, 5000, 3696, 3661, 2953, 479, 5000, 3696, 3661, 2953
```

The following table is clearly static. However, if you were going to involve dynamic SQL (which is not recommended in T-SQL but obviously doable), the population of this next table would be the only part.

```
Declare @X_Table_Normalized Table
    (
    Id int not null
    , Ordinal int not null
    , Name varchar(10) not null
    , Value float not null
    )

Insert @X_Table_Normalized( Id, Ordinal, Name, Value )
Select Id, 1, 'x1', x1 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 2, 'x2', x2 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 3, 'x3', x3 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 4, 'x4', x4 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 5, 'x5', x5 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 6, 'x111', x111 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 7, 'x112', x112 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 8, 'x113', x113 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 9, 'x114', x114 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 10, 'x115', x115 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 11, 'x11', x11 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 12, 'x12', x12 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 13, 'x13', x13 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 14, 'x14', x14 From @X_Table
Union All Select Id, 15, 'x15', x15 From @X_Table
```

#### Table 1 - Sum by (original) column

```
Declare @Table1 Table
    (
    Id int not null
    , Name varchar(25) not null
    , Ordinal int not null
    , Value float not null
    )

Insert @Table1( Id, Name, Ordinal, Value )
Select Row_Number() Over( Order By Ordinal, Name )
    , Name, Ordinal, Sum(Value)
From @X_Table_Normalized
Group By Ordinal, Name
```

#### Table 2 - Product-Sums by (original) column

```
Declare @Table2 Table
    (
    Id int not null
    , Name varchar(25) not null
    , Ordinal int not null
    , Value float not null
    )

Insert @Table2( Id, Name, Ordinal, Value )
Select Row_Number() Over ( Order By T1.Ordinal, T1.Name, T2.Ordinal, T2.Name ) As Id
    , 'Sum(' + T1.Name + '*' + T2.Name + ')' As Name
    , T1.Ordinal + 100 * T2.Ordinal
    , Sum( T1.Value * T2.Value ) As Value
From @X_Table_Normalized As T1
    Join @X_Table_Normalized As T2
        On T2.Id = T1.Id
Where T1.Ordinal <= T2.Ordinal
Group By T1.Name, T1.Ordinal, T2.Name, T2.Ordinal
```

#### Table 3 - Product-Sums diagonally by (original) column

```
Declare @Table3 Table
    (
    Id int not null
    , Name varchar(25) not null
    , Ordinal int not null
    , Value float not null
    )

Insert @Table3( Id, Name, Ordinal, Value )
Select Row_Number() Over ( Order By T1.Ordinal, T1.Name, T2.Ordinal, T2.Name ) As Id
    , 'Sum(' + T1.Name + '*' + T2.Name + ')' As Name
    , T1.Ordinal + 100 * T2.Ordinal
    , Sum( T1.Value * T2.Value ) As Value
From @X_Table_Normalized As T1
    Join @X_Table_Normalized As T2
        On T2.Id = T1.Id
Where T1.Ordinal = T2.Ordinal
Group By T1.Name, T1.Ordinal, T2.Name, T2.Ordinal

Select * From @Table1 Order By Ordinal
Select * From @Table2 Order By Ordinal
Select * From @Table3 Order By Ordinal
```

---

#### Populating the normalized table with dynamic SQL

Depending on how this is used, you might encapsulate the population of the normalized table using dynamic SQL. If you do, you will need to use real tables or temp tables as opposed to temp variables. That code might look something like:

```
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max)

Set @Sql = 'Insert #X_Table_Normalized_Dynamic( Id, Ordinal, Name, Value )|'
Select @Sql = @Sql + ' Union All Select Id'
    + ', ' + Cast( Row_Number() Over ( Order By ORDINAL_POSITION ) As varchar(10) )
    + ', ' + QuoteName(COLUMN_NAME, '''')
    + ', ' + QuoteName(COLUMN_NAME)
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where TABLE_NAME = 'MySourceTable'

Set @Sql = Replace( @Sql, '| Union All ', ' ')

Exec( @Sql )
```

Comment: Excuse me so, If I need to do operations in bigger tables (instead of 5 columns, more than 30), Dou you recommend using `Dynamic SQL`? How would that dynamic version look like?

Comment: @darkcminor - Only one table would need to be populated via dynamic SQL (`@X_Table_Normalized` in my example but you would need to use temp tables instead of temp variables of course). Whether you use dynamic SQL depends greatly on the manner in which this routine would be used. If once a night in a batch on an automated job, fine.

Comment: @darkcminor - I appended some additional code to show what the dynamic SQL might look like.

Comment: @Thomas  when having more than 10 columns I am getting  `1 x1 8029145
2 x10 15453498
3 x11 13909514
4 x12 11336348
5 x13 11598240` Is there some way to sort them by `Name` `x1,x2,x3,x4,x5...,x9,x10,x11`....   instead `x1,x10,x11,x19,x2,x3`....?

Comment: @darkminor - Sure. Use `01x`, `02x` etc instead. However, I assumed that `x1` was a column name not something to actually be used. Another solution is to add the column's ordinal to the grouping and sorting.

Comment: Howq would be in code: `add the column's ordinal to the grouping and sorting`?

Comment: @darkcminor - Instead of `Group By T1.Name, T2.Name`, you would have `Group By T1.Name, T1.Ordinal, T2.Name, T2.Ordinal` and then you sort on the ordinal (the position of the column) instead of the column name and avoid the problem of `x1` vs. `x01`.

Comment: @Thomas: obviously I would have to change this in all queries you gave... wouldn't I??

Comment: @Thomas: Ok I undestood, I did what you say group by Name and sort by ordinal  `SELECT Row_Number() Over( Order By Ordinal )
    , Name, Sum(Value)
 FROM #X Group By Name, Ordinal` and it works really great

Comment: @darkcminor - I've expanded my answer to illustrate. In short, when you populate @X_Table_Normalized, you pass in a sort order for the columns. You then use that ordinal in the other queries to do your sorting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking another aproach here but why don't you just create a view and derive your other tables from that.

**Advantage**

- Much faster as everything is still set based.
- More readable

**Dynamic Created View**

```
DECLARE @Statement VARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE VIEW VIEW_OriginalTable (ID, Name, Value) AS (' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
SELECT  @Statement =  @Statement 
                      + 'UNION ALL SELECT ' 
                      + CAST(ORDINAL_POSITION AS VARCHAR(32)) 
                      + ', ''' 
                      + COLUMN_NAME
                      + ''', SUM('
                      + COLUMN_NAME
                      + ') FROM OriginalTable'
                      + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'OriginalTable'
SELECT @Statement = REPLACE(@Statement, 'UNION ALL SELECT 1,', 'SELECT 1,') + ')'
EXEC (@Statement)
GO
```

**Three result tables**

```
/*
  Table1
*/    
SELECT  *
FROM    VIEW_OriginalTable

/*
  Table2
*/    
SELECT  [ID] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.ID)
        , [Name] = t1.Name + '*' + t2.Name
        , [Value] = t1.Value * t2.Value
FROM    VIEW_OriginalTable t1
        INNER JOIN VIEW_OriginalTable t2 ON t2.ID >= t1.ID

/*
  Table3
*/    
SELECT  [ID] = t1.ID
        , [Name] = t1.Name + '*' + t1.Name
        , [Value] = t1.Value * t1.Value
FROM    VIEW_OriginalTable t1
```

Comment: Also, How would you do the `UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'x1', SUM(x1) FROM OriginalTable, x2,x3,x4,...,xn` dinamically, as I could have a table with lots of attributes?

Comment: @darkcminor - as I said, that is the disadvantage. It is not dynamically but you should ask yourself *how many times does a column get added to the original table*? The view itself is easy enough to expand and maintain. The selects need no adjustment.

Comment: @Lieven: Yes,I deleted that comment, but what I would like to have is a more general way of doing it... for any number of columns....

Comment: maybe using a loop `while`, and using a var as a `@template` as in my original aproach

Comment: @darkcminor - I have added a dynamic created view to the solution.

Comment: @darkcminor- if you plan to use this in a stored procedure and pass a table name as parameter, you should be aware of possible SQL Injection attacks. Better would be to use sp_executeSQL and add QUOTENAME around @TableName variables. Look here for more information on that : http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames

Comment: @Lieven, I compare the results, and I am not getting the same, And I know why, I need computing for example `SUM(xi*xj)`, wich is different to `SUM(xi)*SUM(Xj)` result that is stored in the VIEW, for example supose `x1` has `10,15,20,8`  and `x2` has `5,5,6,6`   in the answer we get `(10+15+20+8=53)*(5+5+6+6=22)  = 1166`, but I need `(10*5 + 15*5 + 20*6 + 8*6) = 261`, How to change your answer??

Comment: @darkcminor - thank you for the update. I'm a bit late but it seems the problem has been solved adequately by Thomas in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you @Lieven. I upvoted your answer for a nice answer anyway.